# Trying to figure out how to set repeat interval on UILocalNotification

Tags: ios

I'm trying to right a app that will send off a locl alert every n days (set by user) and then end after it has gon off 4 times.

I loked at apples documention and there is a propery called repeatInterval .  I don't understand how this works becouse the apple's documention says it is a NSCalendarUnit,

the second issue is can i tell it how many times to go off>

as of now my test code looks like

```
NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date]
                     dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc]
                                    init];
if (notifyAlarm)
{
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertTime;
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Staff meeting in 30 minutes";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortulatly, there is no way to choose a custom repeatInterval. repeatInterval is of type NSCalendarUnit which is an enum that let you choose like "each day" or "each week" but no "each 4 days".

Moreover, there is no way to choose the repeat count.

I recommend using instead many UILocalNotification with different fireDate since the OS authorizes you to schedule up to 128 local notifications at the same time.

Comment: Hi,I was sort of figuring I would have to use multiple alerts, but really did not like that idear,